# Convert different values DateTime and TimeSpan to the same type?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to compare two date values but they are in different formats. I am getting the LastBootTime from WMI which I convert to DateTime - but the name I get in powershell defines it as "`System.TimeSpan`"

The other type is from Get-EventID and TimeGenerated member. That shows up as "`System.DateTime`".

How do I convert the two above to the same Type so I can compare them?

I basically want to see if what I get back from WMI (the day) is the same as the day in which the eventlog is showing a specific eventid.

The full code is below and in this example it is showing if the difference is 12 hours between the two entries.

The two that are different are the below:

```
$LastBoot = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer).LastBootUpTime
$WMIsysuptime = (Get-Date) – [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($LastBoot)


PS C:\Users\gaachm5\Documents> ($WMIsysuptime).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                              
True     True     TimeSpan                                 System.ValueType
```

This is the other value:

```
$sysuptime = (get-eventlog -ComputerName $computer -LogName System | where-object {$_.EventID -eq "6009"} | select -First 1)[0].TimeGenerated

PS C:\Users\gaachm5\Documents> ($sysuptime).gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                              
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType
```

CODE:

```
clear

$server_event = Get-Content -Path "c:\Temp\Servers.txt"

foreach($computer in $server_event)
{

    try 
    {
        (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet)


        $LastBoot = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer).LastBootUpTime
        $WMIsysuptime = (Get-Date) – [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($LastBoot)

        $WMIdays = $WMIsysuptime.Days
        $WMIDaystoHours = ($WMIsysuptime.Days)*24
        $WMIhours = $WMIsysuptime.hours
        $WMITotalHours = $WMIDaystoHours + $hours

        $sysuptime = (get-eventlog -ComputerName $computer -LogName System | where-object {$_.EventID -eq "6009"} | select -First 1)[0].TimeGenerated

        $days = $sysuptime.Day
        $DaystoHours = ($sysuptime.Day)*24
        $hours = $sysuptime.hour
        $TotalHours = $DaystoHours + $hours

        #$dateget = Get-Date -Format d

        if($TotalHours -gt '12')
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName GSITWinTradFRA -Source RPcMon -EntryType Error -EventId 5 -Message "$computer - FAILED - Servers Uptime is GREATER then 12 hours or not contactable - Uptime from EVENT LOG shows: $days Days and $hours Hours - This is the Sunday patching run. Uptime from WMI shows: $WMIdays and $WMIhours"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName GSITWinTradFRA -Source RPcMon -EntryType Information -EventId 4 -Message "$computer - SUCCESS - Servers uptime is less than 12 hours - Uptime is $days Days and $hours Hours - This is the Sunday patching run"
        }
    }
    catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName GSITWinTradFRA -Source RPcMon -EntryType Error -EventId 5 -Message "$computer - FAILED - Server is not contactable - This is the Sunday patching run"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the lastbootuptime from wmi in DateTime format, try:

```
$LastBoot = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer) | %{$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}
```